# How to reduce outgoing resolution of remote desktop [Ubuntu > Win10]

Tags: windows-10, display-resolution, remote-desktop

I have a computer with Ubuntu 22.04 connected to a 4k screen and a Windows 10 computer connected to a FullHD screen.

I am connecting from Windows to Ubuntu using Remote Desktop Connection (gnome-remote-desktop on the Linux side). Due to resolution mismatch I have a full screen image of a quarter of the Ubuntu desktop which I need to move around using sidebars. **Is there a way to change the resolution only for the remote connection?**

Changing resolution settings in Remote Desktop Connection only makes the window smaller but the inside is still a 4k image that needs bars to navigate.

[EDIT] Clarification of Ubuntu version

Comment: In such a case, sorry for misunderstanding. It's 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its possible to change the resolution of the remote connection by adjusting the settings on the Ubuntu side.
You can use the command "xrandr" to change the resolution of the remote session.
You should run the command in the terminal of the remote Ubuntu machine.
Here is how to change the output using that package:

```
xrandr --output <output> --mode 1920x1080
```

(if it doesn't work try adding a sudo infront of the command)
If you want to, You can also add the command to your startup applications so that it runs automatically every time you connect to the remote Ubuntu machine.

Another way is it, to install the gnome tweaks which is a UI for tweaking many settings for gnome DE including display.
You can then change the resolution under "Top Bar".

Comment: Any idea what <output> might be for remote desktop? When I typed `xrandr` I only got display ports (one connected), so the method worked with DP-2 but logically that changed the resolution on the large display too, not only remote

Regarding gnome tweaks I only have clock and calendar options in "Top Bar"

Answer (score 0):

at first step call

`xrandr --listmonitors`

to identify the name of the **<output>**, example:

`Monitors: 1 0: +*default 1360/360x768/203+0+0  default`

where **default** is your **<output>**

or

`Monitors: 1 0: +*XWAYLAND0 2560/310x1440/170+0+0  XWAYLAND0`

where **XWAYLAND0** is your **<output>**

Comment: Running `xrandr --listmonitors` in PuTTY gives "Can't open display".